# SDL Web 8.5/8.1 Page component presentation preview image not loading.

Tags: web8

Yesterday I am installed new SDL Web8.5 and also installed custom MSI. It`s working fine SDL Web8.5 without my custom MSI. I try to preview image from page presentation and i got this error(/WebUI/Editors/CME/icon.png?uri=tcm:808-35597 404 (Not Found)) . any one have solution for this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share how this image is rendered in your template? Does it show when you preview in your old environment?

Comment: thanks for response Nuno, it`s working after i changed my code into "/WebUI/Editors/Base/icon.png?uri=tcm:808-35597"

Comment: Please refer [solution](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/web8-5-multimedia-component-images-not-loading-properly) for this issue