# Web8.5: Multimedia component images not loading properly

Tags: web8, web8.5

Multimedia component image not loading properly in SDLWEB8 and got error "HTTP 404: File not found, reverting to mimetype". I think some configuration setup missing.

Any one have solution for this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WIX configuration over-write the default value. Final updated the below code and working fine.

\tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config

/ThumbnailCache

Answer (score 3):

Just for future references, we had similar issue where our thumbnails were not being loaded in same manner. After gruesome debugging we found out that the problem was in firewall blocking connections from media manager.

I just wanted to point that that that can be cause of problem also. :)